# Using a Select query inside a select query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> I am trying to use a select query within another select query in the from clause.This is a mysql query.

```
SELECT invoiceNo, SUM(weight), COUNT(barcode), sum_total
FROM (SELECT * FROM `selected_items` WHERE date LIKE '07-Jan-2016' ORDER BY id DESC)
WHERE date LIKE '07-Jan-2016' GROUP BY invoiceNo;
```

> This is how my database looks like.
>   [image]
>   How can I achieve something like this where I have a table which I order by id desc and use another select query on the result of this query.The above query gives me an error #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias.Can anyone help I am new to programming.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM  selected_items WHERE date LIKE 07-Jan-2016 ORDER BY id DESC`  run this query in phpmyadmin and see what is  outcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this will help you out .

```
SELECT invoiceNo, SUM( weight ) , COUNT( barcode ) , sum_total
FROM (SELECT * FROM  `selected_items` 
WHERE DATE LIKE  '07-Jan-2016'
ORDER BY id DESC
)a
GROUP BY invoiceNo;
```

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get it why you are using sub-query. You can directly use the table 'selected_items' and check the condition in where clause.Like:

```
SELECT invoiceNo, SUM(weight), COUNT(barcode)
from 'selected_items'
WHERE date LIKE '07-Jan-2016' 
GROUP BY invoiceNo
Order By Id
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do order by inside inner select query. And in MySQL, you need to give an alias to a derived table, `a` in this example.

```
SELECT invoiceNo, SUM(weight), COUNT(barcode), sum_total
FROM 
(
SELECT * FROM `selected_items` WHERE date LIKE '07-Jan-2016'
) a
WHERE date LIKE '07-Jan-2016' GROUP BY invoiceNo;
```

Without looking at data, it is difficult to decide to `order by` but this query will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

You're query is almost right. However there's only missing. You must used an ALIAS.

SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT * FROM @table
)AS tbl1 WHERE field1 = 'test'